# I want to find the first blank line in a file and write text in it but it wont write?

Tags: python

I want to get make a code that lets you enter text into an entry and hit a button and have that text be put on the first blank line of a .txt document called List.txt but it doesn't print it. it works when the `def add_list(self)` looked like this.

```
    file = open("List.txt", "w")
    file.write(self.info.get())
    file.close()
```

I think it just doesnt read the file but im not sure.

```
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        Label(self, image=self.image).place(relx=0, rely=0, anchor=NW)
        Label(self, text="Enter any additional Instructiuons for the day:", background="#3f49e5").place(relx=.0, rely=.45)
        self.info = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.info).place(relx=.0, rely=.51)
        Button(self, text="Add to Todays List", command=self.add_list).place(relx=.24, rely=.51)




    def add_list(self):
        infile = open("List.txt", "r+")
        for line in infile:
            if not line.strip():
                continue
            else:
                infile.write(self.info.get())
                infile.close()
```

Comment: Opening with `w` truncates the file

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about your use case but if you just wanna add a new line to a file use this

```py
with open("List.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write("\n" + self.info.get())
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in the line `infile = open("List.txt", "r+")` you need to read its text like this:

```
infile = open("List.txt", "r+").read()
```

what you did is just create a file pointer, it doesn't have the text. Also consider using `with` for opening files, since it will close it at the end, for example:

```
with open("List.txt", "r+") as file:
    text = file.read()
    # process it
    pass
    # it will be closed in the end automatically
```

Comment: ok that worked like a charm if you add a "\n" + infront of the .get()

Comment: @PatLarkin good, can you upvote the answer and select it as the accepted solution?